# adding new axes to facilitate broadcast, a better way?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting

I am looking for a nice way to "clean up" the dimensions of two arrays which I would like to combine together using broadcasting.In particular I would like to broadcast a one dimensional array up to the shape of a multidimensional array and then add the two arrays. My understanding of the broadcasting rules tells me that this should work find if the *last* dimension of the multidimensional array matches that of the one dimensional array. For example, arrays with shapes (,3) and (10,3) would add fine

My problem is, given how the array I have is built the matching dimension happens to be the *first* dimension of the array so the broadcasting rules are not met. For reference my one d array has shape (,3) and the multi-dimensional array is (3,10,10,50).

I could correct this by reshaping the multi-dimensional array so that the compatible dimension is the last dimension but I'd like to avoid this as I find the logic of reshaping tricky to follow when the different dimensions have specific meaning.

I can also add empty dimensions to the one dimensional array as in the code below until the one dimensional array has as many dimensions as the high dimensional array as in the code snippet below.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],
>>>               [3,4],
>>>               [5,6]])
>>> b = np.array([10,20,30])
>>> a+b[:,None]
array([[11, 12],
   [23, 24],
   [35, 36]])
```

This gives me my desired output however in my case my high dimensional array has 4 different axes so I would need to add in multiple empty dimensions which starts to feel inelegant. I can do something like

```
b = b[[slice(None)] + 3*[np.newaxis]]
```

and then proceed but that doesn't seem great. More generally one could imagine needing an arbitrary number of new axes on both sides of the original one dimension and writing a helper function to generalize the above logic. Is there a nicer/clearer way to achieve this?

Comment: `np.expand_dims` uses `a.reshape(shape[:axis] + (1,) + shape[axis:])`.  Is that any prettier?  `np.stack` uses `arr[(slice(None),) * axis + (_nx.newaxis,)]`.

Comment: Just to be safe, convert your indexing list to a tuple.  Otherwise you might get a `FutureWarning`.  `b[tuple([slice(None)]+3*[None])]` or `b[(slice(None),)+3*(None,)]`

Comment: I don't know what is mean by `shape[axis:]` and `shape[:axis]` in your comment about `np.expand_dims`? Also thank you for the note on tuples for indexing over lists.

Comment: Oh I see now. It is adding the new axis in in the appropriate place with in the shape of the array. I will think about this option. But it seems like I will still need to add in each of axes or expanded dimensions by hand no matter what.

Comment: A brief method that I personally like is `np.r_[f"0,{n},{k}", b]`. This would make `b` `n` dimensional by prepending `k` ones to the shape and appending as many as required to bring the length of shape to `n`.

Comment: My point is that there's nothing wrong with building an indexing tuple by regular python methods.  Or a reshape tuple.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't know. `numpy` is great, but this kind of operation could do with a more intuitive interface. Maybe something `einsum` like. Wouldn't it be neat if one could just do `b['i->iNNN']` or even `b['i->i3N']` to append 3 new axes? Or `b['ii->i']` to extract the diagonal, or `b['ijkl->(ik)(jl)']` to swap the middle two axes and then reshape from 4D to 2D?

Comment: In my experience expanding an array with `[:,None,None]` isn't a common enough case to merit special notation.  `np.atleast_3d` uses `[None,:,None]` instead.  `np.expand_dims` could have been written to add more than one dimension, but deliberately avoids that (and will raise an AxisError in the future).

Comment: Yes, what @PaulPanzer was describing in the comments is the sort of thing I was looking for. I don't fully understand the approach with np.r_. For now I've chosen to go with the approach I indicated in the original question of explicitly creating the slice object with the shape I need. Thank you for the suggestions.